# IOS JSON Parsing

Tags: ios, json

I'm aware of how to parse a JSON data with all the key pair values. Check the below JSON

{
    "a": [
        "a1",
        "a2",
        "a3"
    ],
    "b": [
        "b1",
        "b2",
        "b3"
    ]
}

in this the key values a and b are not static key values . They are dynamic key values. How do i parse this one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know they are Arrays:

```
NSDictionary *parsedData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:&error];

for (NSString *key in [parsedData allKeys])
{
  // you have now a key to an array
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   //Get json data in Dictionary
json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &error];

NSLog(@"%@",json);

NSArray * responseArr = json[@"Deviceinfo"];   // Here you need pass your key

for(NSDictionary * dict in responseArr)
{

    [delegate.firstArray addObject:[dict valueForKey:@"a"]];
}
```

Try this code...

Answer (score 0):

To convert JSON to NSDictionary:

```
NSError *error= nil; 
NSDictionary *parsedDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&error];
```

parsedDictionary will be

```
parsedDictionary = {
a = [a1,a2,a3],
b = [b1,b2,b3]
};
```

To get all keys in dictionary

```
NSArray *allKeys = [parsedDictionary allKeys];
```

To get a and b arrays in dictionary

```
for (NSString *key in allKeys)
{

NSArray *a = parsedDictionary[key];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use my method for json parsing,

**Parse Method:**

```
    -(void)jsonDeserialize:(NSString *)key fromDict:(id)content completionHandler:(void (^) (id parsedData, NSDictionary *fromDict))completionHandler{
    if (key==nil && content ==nil) {
        completionHandler(nil,nil);
    }
    if ([content isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
        for (NSDictionary *obj in content) {
          [self jsonDeserialize:key fromDict:obj completionHandler:completionHandler];
        }
    }
    if ([content isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
        id result = [content objectForKey:key];
        if ([result isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]] || result == nil) {
            NSDictionary *temp = (NSDictionary *)content;
            NSArray *keys = [temp allKeys];
            for (NSString *ikey in keys) {
             [self jsonDeserialize:key fromDict:[content objectForKey:ikey] completionHandler:completionHandler];
            }
        }else{
            completionHandler(result,content);
        }
    }
}
```

**Method Call:**

```
 NSData *content = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"Sample" ofType:@"json"]];
    NSError *error;
```

> //to get serialized json data...

```
   id dictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:content options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
```

> //get data for key called *GetInfo*

```
     [self jsonDeserialize:@"GetInfo" fromDict:dictionary completionHandler:^(id parsedData, NSDictionary *fromDict) {
            NSLog(@"%@ - %@",parsedData,fromDict);
        }];
```